# custom json deserialization when key is not there

Tags: c#

I'm writing a custom json deserializer and I'm writing this:

```
public class MyObjectToJson : JavaScriptConverter
{
public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
{
    MyObject TheObject = new MyObject; 

    TheObject.TheValue = serializer.ConvertToType<string>(dictionary["TheValue"]);
```

What happens if the json object doesn't contain a key TheValue? Does this code crash or just continues with TheObject.TheValue = ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will throw an exception. You can avoid by checking whether `dictionary.ContainsKey("TheValue")` before calling `dictionary["TheValue"]`.